# Format of OpenSSL OCSP responder index file

Tags: ssl, openssl, ocsp

I am trying to set up the simple OpenSSL OCSP responder server, using the following command:

```
openssl ocsp -index index.txt -port 9999 -rsigner ocsp_cert.pem -rkey ocsp_key.pem -CA root_cert.pem -out ocsp.log -text
```

and it works and waits for requests as long as `index.txt` is empty. once I fill it in with any content (specifically following this format: [CA Database](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cadb.html)), the OCSP responder server exits right away.
The content of `index.txt` is:

```
V   211118000000Z   3039    unknown /C=IN/ST=TamilNadu/O=cbe/CN=test
```

Why is the server exiting? is the format correct?
Also - are spaces allowed in the "subject" fields?

Comment: You don't have two tabs between expire-time and serial as required -- even when revoke-time is empty it must be delimited. For me this outputs `wrong number of fields on line 1 (looking for field 6, got 5, '' left)` on stderr (and exited) when it received a request, which pretty clearly indicates the problem -- didn't yours? PS: this isn't a programming or development question.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Thank you! I don't see any errors even when redirecting stderr to a file. what might be the reason for it?
I am using OpenSSL 1.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: {DonAdams} A-ha! {/} My test system was 1.0.2k on CentOS7; I went to my offline OpenSSL dev system to check more thoroughly and yes, the print was removed in 1.1.0 up, so 1.1.0 exits silently on the first request, and due to a minor code reorg 1.1.1 exits silently immediately at startup, just as you observed. (It looks like they tried to replace the print with an error code -- but it's in an object that's discarded, so that doesn't actually work. Yuck.)